# Incorrect URL with named routing outlet in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am writing following code for routing:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([{
    path: 'list/open',
    component: SWAOrderAppComponent,
    children: []
  }, {
      path: 'list/:orderId',
      component: SWAOrderPackageComponent,
      outlet: 'popup'
    }, {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'list',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }])],
  exports: [RouterModule,]
```

and using following code to navigate to route "list/911" with named outlet 'popup'

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: "list/"+ id }}]);
```

This is loading correct component but i am getting following url with this route:

```
https://host/list(popup:list/911)
```

I want URL of format
    https://host/list/911

Comment: Got it through a hack, used { skipLocationChange: true } in navigate function and used this.location.go("") to put desired URL